# Embedded YouTube video Jinja2 - Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to add an embedded YouTube video within my Flask App.

The Database stores YouTube URL

This is my Model:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    video = db.Column(db.String(450))

@app.route('/post/<id>')
def post(id):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    return render_template('post.html', post = post)
```

My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
      <div class="media">
        <iframe width="100%" src="{{post.video}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Example:

In database are stored URLs:

```
id|video
1 |https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5XvLJrW6Fg
```

In web browser is rendered:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5XvLJrW6Fg" allowfullscreen="" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but doesn't display the video.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the embed link of the video. In this case it would be,

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q5XvLJrW6Fg" allowfullscreen="" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I will use more than one video, and It will not always be the same video.

Comment: Fetch all the video urls that your want to use as list and loop them over in jinja to create an iframe for each video url.

Comment: I tried this:

video = post.video

media =  '<iframe src="'+video+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' 

In template I use {{media}}, but the error continues

Comment: What is the HTML rendered for media ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer includes details to answer the provided question and give extra information to those needing help in obtaining the video id's if they do not already have them. If you already have the video id's you want to include in the template then you can skip the first two code blocks about interacting to the YouTube Data API.

Firstly, to obtain the video id's we can use the YouTube Data API v3 and its associated python library `google-api-python-client`. In this example I will obtain the video id's for of a channels uploaded videos (however any playlist can be used instead).

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

    api_key = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_API_KEY')
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

    yt_channel_request = self.youtube.channels().list(
                part='contentDetails',
                id='UC8Izp0TH30o9qrxGJVAwEuQ'
            )

    yt_channel = yt_channel_request.execute()
    uploads_id = yt_channel['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'] # Playlist ID for the uploads playlist
```

After recieving the id for the uploads playlist, another call has to be made to the YouTube Data API to obtain all of the individual video id's in this playlist.

```
video_ids = []
next_page_token = ''

while next_page_token != None:
    yt_uploads_request = self.youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part='contentDetails',
        playlistId=uploads_id,
        pageToken=next_page_token,
        maxResults=50
    )
    yt_uploads = yt_uploads_request.execute()
    for upload in yt_uploads['items']:
        video_ids.append(upload['contentDetails']['videoId'])

    try:
        next_page_token = yt_uploads['nextPageToken']
    except:
        next_page_token = None
```

There, now all of the video id's have been collected in the `video_ids` list for use in our template. They can be passed as arguments to the `render_template` function like so.

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('main.html', video_ids=video_ids)
```

Finally in our template we can use Jinja2 to loop over all of our `video_ids` and create a separate iframe for each video id.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for video_id in video_ids %}
        <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ video_id }}' frameborder='0' 
        allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
        picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

If you are not already using YouTube Data API to get the video id's I would highly suggest it as any additional videos added to the playlist will also be included on your website (as long you have a separate thread to manage making calls to the API to collect these new video id's on a frequent basis).